# Can't get linq string & int concat for c# .net dropdown

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, linq

```
public ViewResult Index()
{
     var theList = from p in db.theTable
                   select p.Id + p.lastName;

     ViewBag.theList = new SelectList(theList);                             
     return View();
}
```

The preceding code is in my controller and produces the following error:

> *"Unable to cast the type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Object'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting Entity Data Model primitive types."*

I believe the problem is trying to concatenate an int (id) and string (lastName), as either alone works fine and I was able to concat firstName and lastName together.

I tried `ToString()` and `Convert()`, which did not work.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [`StringConvert`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd487158.aspx)

```
 var theList = from p in db.theTable
               select SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)p.Id) + p.lastName;
```

But personally, I prefer to do string manipulation on the client. It gives you more flexibility with how you format your string anyway... like this

```
var theList = from p in db.theTable
               select new { p.Id, p.lastName };
ViewBag.theList = new SelectList(theList);   

...

@foreach(var p in ViewBag.theList)
{
    var str = string.Format("{0}{1}", p.Id, p.lastName);
}
```